# EEPlus currency format with £?

Tags: epplus

I'm using "£#,##0.00" as a number format when creating spreadsheets using EEPlus.

When you look at the spreadsheet created the format has been modified to "\£#,##0.00". This still displays okay in Excel but doesn't if anyone previews the spreadsheet using the viewer on an iPhone. The £ symbol isn't shown and it doesn't limit to only showing two decimal places.

If I use the same format but with the Dollar or Euro symbols, it doesn't have the problem.

Comment: How are you setting the format? Because if I set the format like this `cell.Style.Numberformat.Format = "£#,##0.00";` it works fine and no "\" is added.

Comment: Could not test the ipone part. I dont have one.

Comment: That's exactly how I'm setting the style. I only get the \ with £. If I use $ or € the format goes through without the \. It may be something particular about the build I'm using, I'll try some alternatives.

Comment: The annoying thing is the \ is a perfectly valid character indicating that the £ is a literal. Unfortunately, the built-in viewer on iOS doesn't seem to handle it. If you open the file using iOS Excel App the formatting is correct.